# Hyperlinks in emails to candidates

Tags: support, email, stack-overflow-talent

My company uses Stack Overflow Talent and I'd like to contact some candidates I've found. In the email to the candidates, built through https://talent.stackoverflow.com, I'd like to include one or two links.

Can links be added to the emails?

And if so, how?

There's no editor options. And I can't find myself in the Candidate Search to send a test email.

Comment: I don't use it myself, but if it is allowed, you could paste in the url. Even if isn't clickable for some browsers, least they might just know what to do with it, least I hope so.